# Using jQuery within Opera User JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

I wonder if it's possible to load jQuery within [Opera User JavaScript](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/), so that I can use jQuery functionality in it, even on pages that are not currently using jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it would certainly be possible if you paste the whole lot of jQuery into your UserJS file, or perhaps create a separate UserJS file for all pages with the jQuery library. However, there's a possibility that it would conflict with any pages using jQuery.

Depending on your requirements, maybe you could roll your own mini-framework? For example some simple functions to grab elements by tag/class/id:

```
function $id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Note: you may get a better response over at [Opera's forums](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. An even cleaner way of doing it was to save jquery to the opera userscripts-folder so that it is run on every page. Then i could just use the normal $(document).ready(function() { in my own user javascript file.

Comment: If you copy jQuery to your user JS folder remember that user scripts run in alphabetical order, so perhaps calling it something like 0-jquery.js helps making it run before all other scripts needing it.

(At least we (Opera) implemented alphabetical sorting of user script files back then, don't know if we have explicit tests for that so no idea if it works.. Perhaps I need to fix that.)

Answer (score 8):

I just wrote an Opera userJS, which I transformed from a Google Chrome extension, where jQuery could easy be loaded, but here in Opera I had to use another solution, and I wanted to make minimal changes in my code.

I just append a new script tag in the document's header with a working jQuery source. It starts to get downloaded BEFORE DOM is ready.

This is my working solution, hope that helps!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name This is the name of my userJS
// @description That's the description of my userJS
// @include http://blahblah.hu/*
// @include http://*.blahblah.hu/*
// @match http://blahblah.hu/*
// @match http://*.blahblah.hu/*
// @version 1.0
// ==/UserScript==

(function( ) {

    // include jQuery
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.id = 'myjQuery';
    newScript.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js';
    headID.appendChild(newScript);

    window.addEventListener('load', function (e)  {

        // you can write your jQuery code now!
        $('#yourElementId').css('background-color', 'yellow');

        // further jQuery codes
        // ...

    }, false);

})( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:

I use it regularly with my userJS. Just copy your jquery.js into your userJS folder.

Option 1:

to keep it from conflicting with available jquery, use the noConflict option within the jqueryfile and associate jQuery with with your own identifier (jQueryMyIdentifier = jQuery; jQuery = null;) . your JS code can be wrapped with

```
(function($) {
    // normal jquery js based on, jQueryMyIdentifier
    $('#bla').x();
})(jQueryMyIdentifier);
```

Option 2:

check out, how to include a remote js using javascript. implement that include line into your JS.

```
include "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"
```

or alike.